# Same bounds after substitution on $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x²-\frac{1}{x²}}dx$$ if I do the substitution $u=x²+\frac{1}{x²}$ then as $x\to\infty$, $u\to \infty$ and as $x\to -\infty$, $u\to\infty$ since there is x squared. What do I do? I know the function is even, and I can split the integral in $2\int^\infty_0$ but that seems to get the same bounds as well. What do I do?

**Please do not tell me a solution/method, I still want to try this integral on my own without hints or anything**

Comment: The integral is improper at $x=0$ as it isn't defined there anyways,  so you will need to break it there.  Then it will be improper at both $0$ and $\infty$, so you will need to break it at some point $c$ in between,  so do $0$ to $c$ then $c$ to $infty$

Comment: Check out Glasser's master theorem.

Comment: @Alan wait so, I have to split it into $\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\infty$ since it is undefined at 0 but why do I have to split it again into the c thing?

Comment: @Cameron Williams I already have, and I'm pretty sure that's a suggestion to solve the integral, correct me if I'm wrong on that, but I've specifically mentioned not to suggest anything in the post to help me solve the problem.

Comment: ... Then what are you even trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Cameron Williams read the post, I'm wondering about the substitution I, myself, wrote. Is it simply not a valid substitution to make if the bounds end up being the same?

Comment: It is a valid substitution if the integral is divided multiple integrals.

Comment: @Acyex If an integral is improper on both upper and lower bounds you need to split it up into two at some arbitrary cut point in between and test each separately

Comment: @Acyex: your integral is discussed in the original [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf) of M.L. Glasser. You can still, with pedestrian methods show that the integral converges.

Comment: @Acyex Why are you so upset about the bounds being the same?

Comment: @Alan The function is clearly defined at $x=0$ and is equal to $0$ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain is $]-\infty, \infty[$, the substitution $u=x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$ isn't injective, hence, it gives inconsistency when computing the integral. You can solve this problem by splitting the integral.

Answer (score -1):

$J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}dx.$ since $e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is an even function

$J=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}dx$

substituting $x=\frac{1}{u}$ :we find $J=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2}e^{-u^2-\frac{1}{u^2}}du$

from $(1) $ and $(2)$ we have :

$2J=2\int_0^{\infty }(1+\frac{1}{x^2})e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}dx\implies J=\int_0^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})e^{-((x-\frac{1}{x})^2+2)}dx=e^{-2}\int_0^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x^2})^2}dx$

substituting $v=x-\frac{1}{x}  \implies dv =(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ we find : $J=e^{-2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-v}dv=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2}$

Comment: But what is wrong with my answer?  Using Wolfram Alpha as well, I found the same value as I found in an answer

Comment: (+1) There is nothing wrong with your answer in my opinion. In fact, I think you can provide s proof of  Glasser's master formula using your idea.

Comment: He clearly said that he doesn't want a solution because he wants to try to solve it by its own, so the best thing you can do is to delete your answer.